# Derivatives of a function

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I came across this problem and was wondering if I could get some guidance with this one? 
True / False. Every function f that is differentiable on the closed interval [a,b] is itself the derivative of some function g on the same closed interval [a,b].

I said true but I am not sure. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127225/does-there-exist-a-function-that-is-differentiable-but-not-integrable-or-integr).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the fundamental theorem of calculus you can say "yes".

Loosely speaking, given $f$ differentiable in $[a,b]$ (be careful, I don't remember if there's some request on the fact that the interval should be open) then define $F(x) = \int_{a}^x f$.

Then $\dfrac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x)$.

Comment: It's not obvious that you could write $F$ in term of elementary functions (think to $f= e^{-x^2}$) but, for sure $F$ exists.