# Intuitively, is Integration Easier than Differentiation?

Tags: real-analysis

I wanted to know why is integration on intuitive level much easier and has larger class than differentiable functions ? I would like someone to give me their intuition in regards to this.

Comment: Could you explain specifically what you mean by "much easier on an intuitive level" and in what way integration "has a larger class than differentiable functions"? Different people might have very different impressions of all this than you do, so we'd be very likely to answer a question you didn't mean to ask and not answer the question you wanted.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127227/64601

Comment: I thought math for 34 years with Calc I and Calc II so many times, I forget the number of times and I'd be ready to bet that 99.9% of my students thought that diffentiation was much easier than integration. Also: a CAS, like Maple or Wolfram Alpha will calculate any derivative while it will have difficulty integrating even simple functions.

Comment: Differentiable functions are all continuous and hence integrable, but the converse doesn't hold, intuitively because integration blurs over discontinuities in the function or its derivative (think about step functions or the absolute value function). However, calculating derivatives of a given composite of known differentiable functions is a mechanical process, but finding integrals is not. So it is not clear why you think integration is easier (e.g., consider $f(x) = 1/x$: you have to discover the natural logarithm function to find its integral).

Comment: @DavidK I’m guessing what OP has in mind is the fact that, for instance, in the one-dimensional case definite integrals represent the signed area under the graph of the integrand. Since the derivative is by definition just the rate of growth of a function I don’t get what makes it harder to visualize.

Comment: @Federico that is exactly what I have in mind.

Comment: @RobArthan that is the explanation that I had in mind. Thanks. Can you add that as an answer. I will accept it.

Comment: @BernardMassé. I would expect the intuitive $idea$ of integration may be easier for a beginner to grasp, in terms of areas and volumes.  Although in Newton's time, a formula for $\int \sec x dx$ was, for a significant period of time, an important unsolved problem

Answer (score 4):

Well, for one, I would disagree that integration is easier at least *when it comes to integrating elementary functions symbolically*. For that, differentiation is much easier. Consider, say, finding the integral

$$\int_{0}^{x} \sqrt{\tan x'}\ dx'$$

versus differentiating

$$\frac{d}{dx} \left[x \mapsto \sqrt{\tan x}\right]$$

. The latter is a cakewalk - just an easy application of chain, power, and tangent rules. The former is *very difficult* - so much so that a sort-of-famous math Youtube producer going by the name of "blackpenredpen" made a video on it. And let's not forget that a lot of elementary functions do not integrate to elementary functions at all, which in part occasioned the accumulation of a wealth of additional functions, e.g.

$$\int e^{-x^2}\ dx$$

and the associated (up to a factor) function called the "error function", $\mathbb{erf}$.

However, there *is* something you get on here that is rather interesting and that is that integrals are *more widely applicable* in some sense: differentiation requires a "suitably-smooth" function, while integration can work even on some discontinuous functions - in its most general form, the (oriented) Lebesgue Integral, you can even integrate the crazy $1_\mathbb{Q}$, or indicator function of the rationals (sorry: it's 0, on every interval of integration).

And there *is* good intuitive sense for this: Intuitively, integration can be thought of as a kind of "low pass" or "smoothing" filter, while differentiation is a "sharpening" filter - think about the likewise-named functions in a computer graphics program like Photoshop. Already-maximally-sharp things (e.g. discontinuous breaks) can't be sharpened any more, but they sure can be smoothed down.

Mathematically, you can make this a lil more rigorous by considering the effect on Fourier series expansions of periodic functions, which allows us to create a notion of frequency and harmonics. In particular, let a standard periodic function be given by

$$h(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cos(nt) + b_n \sin(nt)$$

The $n$th harmonic component has angular frequency $n$ (think in "rad/s", if time $t$ is in seconds), thus actual frequency $f_n = \frac{n}{2\pi}$ (think "Hz").

If you differentiate, you get

$$\frac{dh}{dt}(t) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n a_n [-\sin(nt)] + n b_n \cos(nt) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} n [b_n \cos(nt) - a_n \sin(nt)]$$

which phase-shifts, and by noting the multiplying factor $n$ out front, which are, of course, larger for higher harmonics - *exaggerates* higher frequency details, i.e. "sharpen".

Conversely, integration effectively *divides* by $n$, thus *suppressing* high frequency details, i.e. "smooth" or "blur".

Another result of this "smoothing" effect is that integration is a much better-behaved operation *numerically* than differentiation. Numerical differentiation is exquisitely sensitive even to round-off errors, requiring large helpings of additional precision (which means that when it comes to even getting near a "machine epsilon" worth, you need fake extended-precision arithmetic which is inefficient). But numerical integration is very stable.