# Calculus proof HELP.

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove the following inequalities. If for some numbers $m$, $M$,
$$m ≤ f′(x) ≤ M$$
for all $x$ in $(a, b)$ then
$$m(b − a) ≤ f(b) − f(a) ≤ M(b − a)$$

I’m assuming that you need to use Mean Value Theorem to prove this statement, but I am new to the idea of writing proofs and am unsure how to construct the proof using words.

Comment: Hint: Since $f'$ exists it's continuous on the interval. Apply MVT for $f$ on (a,b).$f'(x) = \dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ for some $x \in (a,b)$. Then, use the given inequality to get the desired result.

Comment: I understand that I can substitute for f'(x) using the formula for MVT then multiple the bounds by b-a to arrive at the answer. But is that all that needs to be done for the proof? Do I have to write anything else (ex assumptions) or can I just leave it at that?

Comment: What else you want to do if you've proved the result that you needed to prove?. Obviously you have to show that $f$ satisfies all the  required conditions so that you could invoke MVT.

Comment: Isn't MVT applicable for specific point on the graph where the slope of the tangent is equal to the slope of a secant line? How do we know that this will apply to all points?

Comment: $f'$ is bounded: i.e for ALL $x \in (a,b)$, $m \leq f(x) \leq M$. So, this property holds for that specific point (which you've mentioned) in (a,b) as well.

Comment: So, does (−)≤()−()≤(−) apply to a specific point on the interval (a,b) and ≤′()≤ applies for all x?

Answer (score 2):

No use of the mean value theorem is required.

By integration of each part of the inequality:

$$\int_{a}^{b} m dx \leq \int_{a}^{b} f'(x)dx \leq \int_{a}^{b}Mdx $$

Since m and M are constants:

$$\int_{a}^{b} m dx = m \times (b-a)$$
$$\int_{a}^{b} M dx = M \times (b-a)$$

And by the fundamental theorem of calculus:

$$\int_{a}^{b} f'(x)dx = f(b) - f(a)$$

You get your desired inequality by plugging in those values:

$$\boxed{m \times (b-a) \leq f(b) - f(a) \leq M \times (b-a)}$$

Comment: How do you know if $f'$ integrable?

Comment: You can't assume that $f'$ is integrable. See https://math.stackexchange.com/a/127269/641014

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $f'(\xi)=\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$ for some $\xi\in(a,b)$, by the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 0):

By the Mean Value Theorem there exists a value, $c$, such that

$$f'(c)=\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}$$

Since $$m ≤ f′(x) ≤ M$$ for all $x$ in $(a, b)$

We can infer

$$m ≤ f′(c) ≤ M$$

Which becomes

$$m ≤ \frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a} ≤ M$$

This can be simplified to

$$m(b-a) \leq f(b)-f(a) \leq M(b-a)$$